# Using LIMIT 1 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

When is it appropriate to add LIMIT 1 at the end of the query in MySQL. I normally add it in DELETE but I've seen it being used with INSERT a and even UPDATE. Is it an overkill or a good practice?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, if you use EXPLAIN you'll see that it speeds things up, as once it's found one result, it stops.

It's also a failsafe – if you know your insert of update should only ever affect one row, by specifying it, you are guaranteeing that it won't ever go wrong and mess up multiple rows.

Comment: Not today, but I'm pretty sure that in the past I have optimised queries that were complex by doing this.

Comment: I know the post is old but rich makes a valid point - once you reach the limit - the requests stop. and also you are ensuring only Limit number is affected.

Answer (score 38):

```
 INSERT INTO .. VALUES () LIMIT 1
```

Doesn't exist. Hopefully you know how many VALUES() you put in there!

```
 INSERT INTO .. SELECT ... LIMIT 1
```

Does exist and is pretty useful, and off topic since the LIMIT is on the SELECT.

```
 DELETE ... LIMIT 1
 UPDATE ... LIMIT 1
```

Extremely rarely useful. Either you know your database enough to be certain that your WHERE matches a UNIQUE condition, or you don't, in which case you should spend a little more time looking at your database and learning SQL.

But ...

```
 UPDATE jobs SET owner=me WHERE owner IS NULL ORDER BY job_submit_time LIMIT 1
```

Can be extremely useful! This makes a near-lockless job queue, where you can come and take a job from the queue without any waiting, locking, or conflict resolution. Quite excellent.

```
 DELETE FROM cache ORDER BY last_update_time LIMIT N
```

Cache takes too much space ? Purge the N oldest rows...

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of an instance where something that speeds up a query and makes it more secure at the same time could be called overkill.  I'll put my vote in the good practice column.

Comment: And with zero downside.

Answer (score 2):

> Extremely rarely useful. Either you know your database enough to be certain > that your WHERE matches a UNIQUE condition, or you don't, in which case you > should spend a little more time looking at your database and learning SQL

There are instances where a limit 1 is REALLY useful.  For example, a table without a unique key.  If we have five of the exact same, then limit one will work.

Comment: A table without a unique key is a surgeon without a scalpel.  A table without a unique key is an excel spreadsheet, and, well.. actually, even excel spreadsheets are stored with row numbers.  Never create a table without a unique key. At least add an auto increment. otherwise, you will eventually go back and add a unique key, and at such time, you will have to update a lot of application code.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you are writing **Forgot Password** code (in PHP):

```
UPDATE
    `users`
SET
    `pass` = PASSWORD('{$new_salted_pass}')
WHERE
    `account_id` = '{$account_id}'
LIMIT 1
```

If your software is a Software as a Service (SaaS),

*and* multiple organizations use your software,

*and* `account_id`-`organization_id` fields together are a unique id,

*and* the account_id is auto-generated in the code like so:

JONES0001
JONES0002
JONES0003
...

*and* the software engineer forgets to add `AND organization_id = '{$organization_id}'` to the query's `WHERE` condition,

*and* the code passes QA when testing the Forgot Password functionality in QA environment,

*and* the code is then pushed to production,

*then* the `LIMIT 1` can limit the damage done when two organizations' user's share the same account_id.